# FOTA download stays at 0% and can not get rid of it on Verizon Ellipsis 7

Tags: ota-update, downloading

I have Verizon Ellipsis 7 (QMV7A) running on Android 4.2.2. I've been stuck with FOTA downloading for 3 days, and it's draining my battery. The download will not progress past 0%. I have tried to stop the download but it just pops back up. I found [the same issue on AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/497401-how-do-i-stop-fota-downloading.html#post4259174), but there's no solution either.

Is there anything that I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on two Verizon Ellipsis 7 tablets. I've called Verizon tech support 3 times; each time I seem to get a tech rep that doesn't seem to understand tech talk. The FOTA process has been running on both tablets for five days, showing 0% progress. On one tablet I did a factory reset. As soon as the device started back up, so did the FOTA process.

**UPDATE (3/4/15)** - I just talked with Verizon technical support, again. They now say it is a known issue with that update and they hope to have it resolved within a couple of weeks.

**UPDATE #2 (3/12/15)** - Verizon now says to return the tablets for repair. They have a special program to address the issue. They will pay the freight, the repairs are free (even if out of warranty), and the return should be within 5 business days.

Comment: Oh yeah, same device model (QMV7A) and Android version (4.2.2) as Mr. Farlight. I am assuming the fota was/is for the KitKat upgrade. It was pushed to me automatically, I did not actively start a download update process.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED  I had the same problem, but I finally got the update to go through.  For nearly a week, the update would hang at 0% and going nowhere.

I reckon turning the WiFi off is the key.  Since it's a Firmware Over The Air (FOTA) update, and the device is programmed to give a Wifi access point priority over a CDMA, GSM, 3G, or LTE, etc. signal, the update just hits a loop.  The update is a primer for the KitKat OS.  Immediately after rebooting and installing, the tablet prompted me to download KitKat.

I doubt it, but it may also be related that I did a manual update (Settings --> About tablet --> software updates --> check new), and kept the tablet awake for ten minutes waiting for the update, then turned off the WiFi connection.  After another couple of minutes, the update went through.